# Vertical align of buttons and text in panel heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to vertical align the buttons with the header text in the following panel - how do I align the text vertically with the buttons?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
        <div class="circle-icon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical circle-icon-glyphicon"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle-icon {
  display: inline-table;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle-icon-glyphicon {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bbn5vfwt/

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap applying `10px` bottom margin for the paragraph. That is the reason is not aligned when you use images. Apply `margin-bottom:0px` for your title paragraph like below.

```
<div class="pull-left">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0px">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbn5vfwt/2/)

Answer (score 1):

> Solution No: 1

```
.panel-heading .pull-left p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

> Solution No: 2

Your HTML will be like this

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <div class="circle-icon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical circle-icon-glyphicon"></span>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
    </div>
  </div>
```

and your CSS will be like this

```
.panel-default>.panel-heading {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.panel-heading.clearfix:before,.panel-heading.clearfix:after {
  content: none;
}
.panel-heading p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.circle-icon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.circle-icon-glyphicon {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #bbb;
    margin-left: 10px; // Added
}
```

Updated your fiddle with solution 2 [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bbn5vfwt/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-bottom` form `p` http://jsfiddle.net/bbn5vfwt/1/

```
p.heading-text {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

> Here `.heading-text` class given to `p`